# Dynamic URL Rewrite rule

Tags: url-rewriting

I need to create a rewrite rule that only runs if an in page variable exists, here is some pseudo code of what I am tying to accomplish.

```
if ($var != null) {
// do something
}

else {
url_rewrite('current_url', 'new url');
}
```

The issue I am running into is that the WordPress built in function requires activation on init and would redirect regardless of whether or not the rule is present.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: rewriting and redirection are two different, unrelated things, it's not clear what your end goal and this variable dependency is.

Answer (score 0):

If you place your if/else statement within the function you call on the `init` hook, the redirect will only occur if your `$var` evaluates to false. For example

```
function 290127_init_validate(){

  if ( ! is_post_type_archive('book') ) {
    return;
  }

  if ($var != null) {
   // do something
  } else {
    wp_redirect('new url');
  }
}
add_action("init", "290127_init_validate");
```

WordPress provides a number of [conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) which can be used to provide even more granular control over when a function should run. You can use these conditional tags at the beginning of your function and `return` early if they don't evaluate to true. The example function above will only run on 'book' custom post type archive page.

Comment: I believe the `init` action hook occurs before the post type is determined, `pre_get_posts` is the [recommended](http://rachievee.com/the-wordpress-hooks-firing-sequence/) action hook to use since it fires after the query variable object is created, but before the actual query is run.